# Has LinkedIn stopped providing connection list download?

Tags: linkedin-api

Until yesterday, this link https://www.linkedin.com/people/export-settings would take you to a page on LinkedIn that provided an option to download your connections in a few different format. Today it doesn't have that option and instead has a link to instructions to download an archive of your data (which is supposedly emailed to you within 72 hours).

I could not find any new about this, and am wondering if this is indeed a change LinkedIn has made for all users going forward.

Comment: Any explanation to go with the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedIn has removed the option to export your contacts. Instead, the company is asking users to request an archive of their data, but that process can take up to 72 hours to complete.

Check this link:

http://venturebeat.com/2015/07/23/linkedin-quietly-removes-option-to-export-contacts-makes-users-wait-up-to-72-hours-for-their-data-archive/

Try this as an alternative:

http://www.linkedinexporttool.com/

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that the link I mentioned above (https://www.linkedin.com/people/export-settings) has been discontinued. Here is a post on LinkedIn forums where the company rep indicates this change in policy:

https://community.linkedin.com/questions/348584/what-happened-to-the-export-connections-function.html